# Making a selection box with custom div frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a "big" selection box ,

```
    <ul>
        <li>
        <div class="sbox">
            <img src=img/typeA.jpg></img><br/>
            <span>Item X</span>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <div class="sbox">
            <img src=img/typeA.jpg></img><br/>
            <span>Item X</span>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <div class="sbox">
            <img src=img/typeA.jpg></img><br/>
            <span>Item X</span>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

When you lick on each "li" , you make a selection , and I will change the border color of it.

But how ? It's not a "" tags , can can you click on that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li div").click(function (e) {
 $(this).css("border-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to handle click on each li and then change the border as a result of the event by changing the class of the li element or adding a border style in css.

Answer (score 0):

below are a few snippets; just put it in the body of an html page and try click a listItem.

```
<ul>
    <li>my li</li>
    <li>another li</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var j = 0, ceiling = lis.length; j < ceiling; j++) {
        lis[j].onclick = function() {
            var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(var i = 0, ceiling2 = lis.length; i < ceiling2; i++) {
                lis[i].style.border = "0px solid white";
            }
            this.style.border = "1px solid green";
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if border is all you need add this to the element tag:

```
onclick="this.style.border='1px solid red'"
```

also add css cursor:pointer to the li to make the hand

Answer (score 0):

Something quick that will play nice with other `li` you could have in your page but you don't want to behave like this "selectable" ones.

First, apply a unique className to `<li>` elements you want to be selectable:

```
<li class="selectable">
```

And then, you can put this jQuery code where you usually initiallize your JS code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("li.selectable").bind('click', function(e) { 
       $(this).find("div.sbox").css('border', '1px solid red'); 
    });
});
```

`$().ready` is a shortcut for document ready. We're going to bind a function when user click `<li>` elements with `selectable` css className. The border will be applied to the inner `div` with className "sbox", following your HTML code.

If you want the border applied to the `<li>` itself, just remove the `find("div.sbox")` part.